# List of tables and figures in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, thesis

I need to add the LIST OF FIGURES and LIST OF TABLES to the TABLE OF CONTENT and adjust some specifications according to the requirements needed to write a thesis by the university. I did this

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=210mm, paperheight=297mm,
left=35mm, right=35mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm}
\parskip=12pt
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdateformat{monthyeardate}{%
     \monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{ makecell}

%LONG TABLE FEATURES
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{} 
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal} 
%%%%%%%%%%%% CAPTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\RequirePackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\NewTblrTheme{captionof}%   % <---
    {\DefTblrTemplate{caption}{default}%
        {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
   \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption}}%
}
 \DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}%
 {\addtocounter{table}{-1}%
  \captionof{table}{\InsertTblrText{caption} "continue..."}
  }%
   }
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \usepackage{adjustbox}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{mathptmx}
   \usepackage{mathtools}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
     \usepackage{fancyhdr}
     \fancyhf{}
     \cfoot{\thepage}
     \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
      \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
      \pagestyle{plain}
      \usepackage{emptypage}

       \renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
        \usepackage{titlesec} 
        \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
                {\bfseries\Large}
                {\chaptername~\filleft\bfseries\fontsize{30} 
                {00}\selectfont\thechapter}{14pt}
               {\vspace{-2em}\filleft\Large}
                [\vspace{0.5em}\titlerule]

     \titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{\thesection}{1em}{} 
               [\vspace{-1.5em}]

     \titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\normalsize{\thesubsection} 
             {1em}{}[\vspace{-1.5em}]

     \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\normalsize 
             {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}[\vspace{-1.5em}]

      \graphicspath{figure/}
       \usepackage{array}
       \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.6}
       \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
       \usepackage{glossaries}
       \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{ragged2e}
          \usepackage{blindtext}
          \renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
          \usepackage{setspace}
          \usepackage{titlesec}
           \newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedleft}

            \pagenumbering{roman}
             \usepackage{marginnote}
             \renewcommand*\contentsname{\null\hfill {TABLE OF 
               CONTENTS}} 
           \usepackage{tocbibind}

        \let\oldaddcontentsline\addcontentsline
         \newcommand{\ADDCONTENTSLINE}[3]{%
         \oldaddcontentsline{#1}{#2}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
               }
          \newcommand{\CAPinToC} 
      {\let\addcontentsline\ADDCONTENTSLINE}
       \newcommand{\noCAPinToC} 
       {\let\addcontentsline\oldaddcontentsline}
       \let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage %remove blank page

       \usepackage{nomencl}%%%% LIST OF SYMBOLS
        \makenomenclature
        \begin{document}
       \input{frontpage.tex}
       \chapter*{\null\hfill{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}}
        \newpage
        \chapter*{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
        \renewcommand\contentsname{\vspace{-3.6em}}
        \tableofcontents
        \newlist{sym}{itemize}{1} %TABLE OF SYMBOLS
       \setlist[sym] 
         {label=,labelwidth=1in,align=parleft,
           itemsep=0.1\baselineskip,leftmargin=!}
         \chapter*{\null\hfill{LIST OF SYMBOLS}} 
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF SYMBOLS}
        \chaptermark{List of Symbols}
         \begin{sys}
          \end{sys}
          \newlength{\mylen}
          \newlength{\tempp}
           \setlength{\tempp}{\cftfignumwidth}
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
             %%%%%% FIGURE %%%%%%%%%%%
            \setlength{\cftfigindent}{0pt}
            \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
            \renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\bfseries \figurename~}
            \renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\normalfont}
            \settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
            \addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}
             \chapter*{LIST OF FIGURES}
             \renewcommand\listfigurename{\vspace{-3.2em}}
             \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
             \listoffigures
             \clearpage
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            %%%%%%%%% TABLE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \setlength{\cfttabindent}{0pt}
            \renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}
            \renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\bfseries \tablename~}
            \renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{\normalfont}
            \settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum\cfttabaftersnum}
            \addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen}
            \chapter*{LIST OF TABLES}
            \renewcommand\listtablename{\vspace{-3.2em}}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
            \listoftables
            \clearpage
            \chapter*{\null\hfill{ABSTRACT}} %ABSTRACT 
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
            \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
            \section{section one} the text starts from here. 
            \section{section tow} the text starts from here.
            \section{section three} the text starts from here.
            \chapter{OVERVIEW}
                \begin{figure}
                    \centering
                     \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example}
                      \caption{A sample figure}
                   \end{figure}

                  \begin{table}
                       \centering
                        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
                         \hline
                           A & B \\
                         \hline
                         1 & 2 \\
                         \hline
                       \end{tabular}
                    \caption{A sample table}
                   \end{table}
                \end{document}
```

what I got is like this
[image]
but I should get it like this
[image]

so I am not sure what is the wrong I did, any help? by the way, I got this warning message when I compiled it [image] The package of hyperref has been inserted in the preamble. By the way, the list of tables and figures should be like this [image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can format your code by highlighting it with your mouse, then clicking on the `{}` icon above the question box.  *I could do it, but that would attach my name to the question, and it's really yours.)  While you're at it, please ,ake the cpde example compilable, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{dpcument}`.  You'll get much better answers that way.

Comment: You might want to use part* in place of chapter*, unless all your chapters are to be formatted the same as the frontmatter stuff.

Comment: I edited the code I hope it is clear now, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ioe-bachelors-proposal-proposal-format-pulchowk-campus/tgksnmyswczd

use this template. In sec folder, you will find the necessary tex files and all you need to this fill them with your own. run main.tex for output.
Here is the thing I adjusted for me

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{report}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\graphicspath{{./sec/image/}}
\geometry{
    left=3cm,
    right=2.5cm,
    bottom=2.5cm,
    a4paper
    }

\title{Thesis}
\author{John MacTavish}
\date{\today}

\sectionfont{\centering}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{}
\makeatother
\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage} 
\pagenumbering{roman} % roman page numbers
\input{sec/titlepage}
%\input{sec/letter_of_approval} % not required for proposal
%\input{sec/copyright} % not required for proposal
%\input{sec/acknowledgment} % not required for proposal
%\input{sec/abstract}
%Table of contents

\newpage
{
  \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
  \renewcommand\contentsname{\centering TABLE OF CONTENTS} % This will change heading text
  \tableofcontents 
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
}

% List of figures - if any

\newpage
\listoffigures 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}

% List of tables- if any

\newpage
\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}

% List of Abbreviation- if any
\newpage
\input{sec/list_of_abbrev}
\input{sec/introduction}
\input{sec/literature_review}
%\input{sec/theoretical_background}
%\input{sec/methodology}
%\input{sec/system_design}
% \input{sec/system_implementation.tex}
%\input{sec/tools_technologies}
% \input{sec/observations}
% \input{sec/result}
%\input{sec/conclusion}
% \input{sec/limitations}
\input{sec/references}
% \input{sec/appendix} %optional
\end{document}
```

you can remove from the lines from 37-39 though and you will get a number section and subsection...

Comment: With a LaTeX not older than 5 years you should neither need `\usepackage{chngcntr}` not `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Why don't you configure the page header and footer in the document preamble instead the body? Your `\addcontentsline` for the `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` adds the *last* page instead of the first one to the table of contents. Loading packages more than once can complicate changes.

Comment: The format of the list of tables and figures should be shown like the above figure. I tried to modify my code as you suggested but it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my question. I have these packages I had to delete to work properly `\usepackage{tocbibind}` and `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.